# How to get information printed in Xcode's console onto screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, nslog

I started using Xcode a couple days ago and I'm completely lost. I'm trying to get a GPS locator app running found [here](https://github.com/shawngrimes/Location-and-Map-Sample).

Basically, the app prints any updated GPS information using NSLog, which as far as my understanding goes, prints to Xcode's console. However, I'd like to get this info printed onto the screen.

Here's the code from CFAStartViewController.m that successfully prints to the screen:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CFAAppDelegate *appDelegate=(CFAAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    CLLocation *currentLocation=appDelegate.locationManager.location;
    self.labelLocationInformation.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %+.6f\nlongitude: %+.6f\naccuracy: %f",
        currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,
        currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,
        currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
}
```

And here's the code in CFAAppDelegate.m that successfully prints to the console:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0)
    {
        //Location timestamp is within the last 15.0 seconds, let's use it!
        if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy<35.0){
            //Location seems pretty accurate, let's use it!
            NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
                newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
            NSLog(@"Horizontal Accuracy:%f", newLocation.horizontalAccuracy);
            //Optional: turn off location services once we've gotten a good location
            //[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the calls to NSLog to self.labelLocationInformation.text, with a similar format to that of CFAStartViewController, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've read through the basic tutorials of Xcode, but I feel there's some knowledge lacking (obviously) on what to do overall.

If the best you could do is post a link that helps me solve this problem, that would be great.

Comment: You need to show "your" code. The code above looks fine so not sure what you are trying to do. You state that both code segments work fine. What are you trying to do that is different from the code presented above? If you want to present the data that is going to NSLog to your UILabel then you need to use newLocation.coordinate.latitude and newLocation.coordinate.longitude in the first code block instead of currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, etc.

Comment: I want the outputs of the second code block to print to the iOS simulator screen but they print in the Xcode console. The code blocks are in two different files, CFAAppDelegate.m and CFAStartViewController.m. I'd like to print values to the screen that are created in CFAAppDelegate.m but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to scope - the `didUpdateToLocation:` method is sent to the location manager delegate, ie your app delegate, which doesn't have the label in scope.  Try changing your delegate for the location manager to be your `CFAStartViewController`, and move the associated location manager delegate code from App Delegate to `CFAStartViewController`.  Then the label will be in scope when didUpdateToLocation: is called.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifying response to my comment.... If you want the data from CFAAppDelegate to be presented in your CFAStartViewController then you need to send that data to CFAStartViewController (or CFAStartViewController needs to get it). To send it 1) provide a storyboard id for CFAStartViewController such as "CFAVC". 2) define or expose properties in CFAStartViewController to contain your data. 3) instantiate CFAStartViewController  via the following from within CFAAppDelegate:

```
// in CFAStartViewController.h define property such as:
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *incomingLocation;

// in CFAAppDelegate.m
// get a pointer to your VC
        CFAStartViewController *destinationVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CFAVC"];

// set properties on VC
destinationVC.incomingLocation = newLocation;

// show CFAStartViewController (or use whatever method you are currently using)
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:YES];
```